# Keeping auth-token between two subdomains

Tags: angular, authentication, token, single-page-application

I have an Angular 7 web app with two different subdomains:
*sub1.myurl.com* and *sub2.myurl.com*

They both have the same login endpoint and all the APIs inside look for auth token.

You can switch a '*namespace*' inside the app, which in some cases forwards you from *sub1* to *sub2* domain and vice versa, which also means page refresh.

Currently I'm keeping my auth token in local storage. So in a scenario when user is redirected from *sub1* to *sub2*, the local storage content changes and the auth-token will be lost.

I've read that cookies would be the solution for that, but once again there might be security issue.

I also tried using [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) but can't find a way to **add general cookie that is available in localhost with no subdomains and also on production environments on sub1.myurl.com and sub2.myurl.com?**

Comment: You can't because the browser determines when to send the cookie data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually figured it out by myself. I'll post my solution here in case anyone ends up with the same problem.

```
   const loc = window.location;
   if (loc.hostname === 'sub1.myurl.com' || loc.hostname === 'sub2.myurl.com') {
      this.cookieService.set('token', session, null, '/', '.myurl.com', true);
   } else {
      this.cookieService.set('token', session);
   }
```

So based on *window.location.hostname* I set cookies differently. For production environment where I have to share cookies between subdomains, putting a dot (.) if front of *domain* parameter, makes it also applicable to subdomains of this domain.

Comment: I tried to make it working with '.localhost' / '.localhost:4200'. I run local server : "ng serve --host localhost --disable-host-check --port 4200 --open" . So I can hit on my local machine http://sub1.localhost:4200 or http://sub2.localhost:4200, or http://localhost:4200. If I try to save a cookie from any subdomain, the cookie will not be persisted under localhost:4200 (what I'm trying to get)